# How to display global errors of a form in different inputs?

Tags: forms, validation, playframework-2.0

I have a form for logging:

```
val loginForm = Form(tuple(
    "email" -> (nonEmptyText verifying email.constraints.head),
    "password" -> nonEmptyText
  )
   .verifying("Email doesn't exist", params => User.findByEmail(params._1) != None)
   .verifying("Password incorrect", params => 
       User.findByEmail(params._1).map(_.checkPassword(params._2)) == Some(true))
)
```

Notice there two global validators in the last. They should be performed only if `email` is not empty and has valid format, and `password` is not empty, so I put the in global.

I want to display `Email doesn't exist` beside `email` input, and `Password incorrect` beside `password` input, how to do that in view?

At present, I use `loginForm.globalError`, but it will show both of them beside one input.

```
@inputText(loginForm("email"), '_label->"Email:",
    '_error->loginForm.globalError
)
@inputPassword(loginForm("password"), '_label->"Password:")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, the global error should stay global, so I'd put it above your inputs:

```
@loginForm.globalError.map { error =>
  <div>@error</div>
}
@inputText(loginForm("email"), '_label->"Email:")
@inputPassword(loginForm("password"), '_label->"Password:")
```

Otherwise you'd have to do something like this:

```
'_error -> loginForm.error("email").orElse(globalError)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the email constraint should be defined on the `email` field rather than globally. And think it makes sense for the password constraint to be global since it checks the pair (email, password).

Comment: I think the existence of `email` should only be checked when email and password both be inputed and email have a valid format, so it put it in global (and I assume all validators perform *fail-on-first*)